# Inline index keyword highlighted

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am trying to write restructuredText markup that, at the same time, creates an entry in the index and highlights the mention in the text. I tried

```
In this chapter, we introduce :index:`*Foo* <Foo>`, a
crucial concept in this example
```

The index entry is created all right, but the text will be

> In this chapter, we introduce *Foo*, a crucial concept in this example

instead of

> In this chapter, we introduce *Foo*, a crucial concept in this example

Can I do do that properly somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a style attribut to `span.xref.std.std-term`? For example in your `source/_static/custom.css`put:

```
@import url("default.css");

span.xref.std.std-term {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

And all index references will be as *italic* …

Comment: It seems the HTML generated here is `we introduce <span class="target" id="index-0"></span>Foo`, so the term itself is not addressable with CSS. And it would not work for the PDF output.

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong: I misread `index`and thought `glossary` hence my test. But why could you not address your `span` element with CSS? However PDF output is indeed another story.

Comment: Because the span element is empty, and the word that I want to highlight comes after.

Answer (score 0):

The best work-around I found so far is

```
In this chapter, we introduce :index:`\ <Foo>`\ *Foo*, a
crucial concept in this example
```